# A JS banner animation using Greensock library

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is JS animation using Greensock's timeline feature as a learning assignment. I don't have a lot of experience with JS so not sure how to optimize it/clean it up. Here's HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="SplitText.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Sainsbury</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="banner-wrapper">
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="text-wrapper">
              <div class="text" id="how-does">How does <br> money <br> off your <br>favourite <br>beer sound?</div>
              <div class="goals-container">
                <div class="text" id="goal">GOAL GOAL GOAL GOAL GOAL GOAL GOAL GOAL</div> 
                <div class="text" id="second-goal">GOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALLLLLLLLLLLLLL</div>  
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="beer-packs">
                <div class="price-buttons-container">
                    <img class="price-button" id="button-1" src="assets/img/button-1.png" alt="">
                    <img class="price-button" id="button-2"  src="assets/img/button-2.png"  alt="">
                    <img class="price-button" id="button-3" src="assets/img/button-3.png"  alt=""> 
                </div>
                <img class="beer" id="stella" src="assets/img/stella.png" alt="Peroni beer cans">
                <img class="beer" id="peroni" src="assets/img/peroni.png" alt="Peroni beer cans">
                <img class="beer" id="kronenbourg" src="assets/img/kronenbourg.png" alt="Peroni beer cans">
            </div>
            <div class="text" id="offer">Sounds like an <br> unmissable offer.</div>
            <div class="cta-container">
                <a href="#"><img id="shop-now" src="assets/img/shop-now-button.png" alt=""></a>
                <img id="drinkaware" src="assets/img/drinkaware-logo.png">
            </div>
            <img class="sainsbury-logo"src="assets/img/sainsbury-logo.png" alt="Sainsbury logo">
        </div>
        <script src="banner.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
gsap.registerPlugin(SplitText);

const beerStella = document.querySelector("#stella");
const beerPeroni = document.querySelector("#peroni");
const beerKronenbourg = document.querySelector("#kronenbourg");
const sainsburyLogo = document.querySelector(".sainsbury-logo");
let firstSplitText = new SplitText("#how-does", {type: "lines,words"});
let secondSplitText = new SplitText("#goal", {type: "lines,words"});
let thirdSplitText = new SplitText("#second-goal", {type: "lines,words"});
let offerSplitText =  new SplitText("#offer", {type: "lines,words"});
const shopNow = document.querySelector("#shop-now");
const drinkAware = document.querySelector("#drinkaware");
const button1 = document.querySelector("#button-1");
const button2 = document.querySelector("#button-2");
const button3 = document.querySelector("#button-3");

gsap.from(firstSplitText.lines, {
    opacity: 0,
    y: 50,
    ease: "back.out(1)",
    stagger: 0.1
  });

let tl = gsap.timeline();

tl.fromTo(beerStella, {
    x: 300,
    duration: 1
},
{
    x: 70
});

tl.fromTo(beerPeroni, {
    duration: 1,
    x: 300 
},
{
    x: 120
}, "<+0.1");

tl.fromTo(beerKronenbourg, {
    duration: 1,
    x: 300 
},
{
    x: 70
}, "<+0.1");


tl.to(firstSplitText.lines, {
    opacity: 0,
    y: -80,
    ease: "back.out(1)",
    stagger: 0.1
  });

tl.to(sainsburyLogo, {
    opacity: 0,
    ease: "back.out(1)",
    stagger: 0.1
}, "<");
 
 
tl.to(beerStella, {
    y: -225,
    duration: 0.5,
    scale: 1.5
}, beerStella+10);

tl.to(beerPeroni, {
    y: -40,
    duration: 0.5,
    scale: 1.3
}, "<");

tl.to(beerKronenbourg, {
    y: 10,
    duration: 0.5,
    scale: 1.4
}, "<");




tl.fromTo(thirdSplitText.lines, {
    x: 300,
    duration: 3
},
{
    x: -1530,
    duration: 3
}, "<");

tl.fromTo(secondSplitText.lines, {
    x: 300,
    duration: 4
},
{
    x: -1200,
    duration: 4
}, "<");


tl.to(beerStella, {
    y: -260,
    duration: 0.5,
    scale: 1.2
});

tl.to(beerPeroni, {
    y: -240,
    duration: 0.5,
    scale: 1.2
}, "<");

tl.to(beerKronenbourg, {
    y: -220,
    duration: 0.5,
    scale: 1.2
}, "<");

tl.to(sainsburyLogo, {
    opacity: 1,
    duration: 0.5
}, "<");

tl.from(offerSplitText.lines, {
    opacity: 0,
    y: 100,
    ease: "back.out(1)",
    stagger: 0.1
  });

tl.fromTo(button1, {
    scale: 0,
    duration: 1,
    opacity: 0,
    ease: "back.out(1)",
    stagger: 0.1
  },
  {
    scale: 1.3,
    opacity: 1
  });

tl.fromTo(button2, {
    scale: 0,
    opacity: 0,
    ease: "back.out(1)",
    stagger: 0.1
},
{
    scale: 1.3,
    opacity: 1
}, "<+0.3");

tl.fromTo(button3, {
    scale: 0,
    opacity: 0,
    ease: "back.out(1)",
    stagger: 0.1
},
{
    scale: 1.3,
    opacity: 1
}, "<+0.3");

tl.from(shopNow, {
    scale: 0,
    opacity: 0,
    ease: "back.out(1)",
    stagger: 0.1,
  });

tl.from(drinkAware, {
    opacity: 0,
    ease: "elastic", // experimenting with ease prop
    stagger: 0.1
}, "<");
```

CSS:

```
/* CSS reset */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

/* end */

@font-face {
    font-family: "MaryAnn-Bold";
    src: url('https://s0.2mdn.net/creatives/assets/3817763/MaryAnn-Bold.woff') format('woff')
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "MaryAnn-Light";
    src: url('https://s0.2mdn.net/creatives/assets/3817763/MaryAnn-Light.woff') format('woff')

}

@font-face {
    font-family: "MaryAnn-ExtraBold";
    src: url('https://s0.2mdn.net/creatives/assets/3817763/MaryAnn-ExtraBold.woff') format('woff')
}




img {
    max-width: 150px;
}
.banner-wrapper {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.banner {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

.text-wrapper {
    justify-content: center;
    max-height: 40%;
    padding: 10px 0px 30px 20px;
}


.text {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: "MaryAnn-ExtraBold";
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: rgb(240, 108, 0);
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 0.92;
    text-align: left;
}

.beer-packs {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
}

#peroni {
    max-width: 100px;
}

.sainsbury-logo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 17px;
}

#offer {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 34px;
    top: 370px;
    left: 20px;
}

.cta-container {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    flex-direction: column;
    top: 470px;
    left: 110px
}

.goals-container {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
}

#drinkaware {
    max-width: 50%;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.price-buttons-container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.price-button {
    max-width: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

#button-1 {
    bottom: 200px;
    left: 20px;
}

#button-2 {
    bottom: 80px;
    left: 85px;
}

#button-3 {
    top: -40px;
    left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! A [runnable snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) could be added if desired, though it may be necessary to find a CDN that offers SplitText.min.js.